# How to print more than one label in spaCy?

Tags: nlp, nltk, spacy

```
nlp = English()
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
pattern1 = [{"LOWER": "iphone"}, {"LOWER": "x"}]
pattern2 = [{"LOWER": "iphone"}, {"IS_DIGIT": True}]
matcher.add("GADGET", None, pattern1, pattern2)

TRAINING_DATA = []

# Create a Doc object for each text in TEXTS
for doc in nlp.pipe(TEXTS):
    # Match on the doc and create a list of matched spans
    spans = [doc[start:end] for match_id, start, end in matcher(doc)]
    # Get (start character, end character, label) tuples of matches
    entities = [(span.start_char, span.end_char, "GADGET") for span in spans]
```

Let's say I have another `matcher.add("Food", None, pattern3, pattern4)`. So how do I pass it through `entities` so that it can select appropriate label?

Answer (score 0):

While the way you are doing this will work, as you've noticed it gets pretty complicated. I would recommend using spaCy's built-in [EntityRuler](https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching#entityruler) instead.

In your case it would look like this:

```
from spacy.lang.en import English

nlp = English()
ruler = nlp.add_pipe("entity_ruler")

patterns =[
 {"label": "GADGET", "pattern": [{"LOWER": "iphone"}, {"LOWER": "x"}]},
 {"label": "GADGET", "pattern": [{"LOWER": "iphone"}, {"IS_DIGIT": True}]},
 {"label": "FOOD", "pattern": ... whatever ... }
]

ruler.add_patterns(patterns)

doc = nlp("Some text") # now your entities are marked
```

Comment: Thanks. In that case how should I create a Doc object for each text in TEXTS? Mainly code for this part # Create a Doc object for each text in TEXTS
for doc in nlp.pipe(TEXTS):
    # Match on the doc and create a list of matched spans
    spans = [doc[start:end] for match_id, start, end in matcher(doc)]
    # Get (start character, end character, label) tuples of matches
    entities = [(span.start_char, span.end_char, "GADGET") for span in spans]

Comment: You don't have to do anything special. Once the EntityRuler is added to your pipeline with `nlp.add_pipe`, any docs you create will automatically have the patterns run and entities labeled. Check the EntityRuler docs I linked to.

Comment: Also as a general note, multi-line code in comments is illegible, it's better if you add it to the end of your question if you need clarification.